# What does it mean by phases in Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

See this picture:[image]

I Saw this picture in wikipedia article: [List of highest-grossing films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films)
I following marvel universe since childhood, but never came across this **PHASE** thing. 
actually what does it mean?

Comment: [Page for Marvel Cinematic Universe films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Films).

Comment: It's sort of like TV seasons.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a categorising term. [Phase One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Phase_One:_Avengers_Assembled) refers to a certain block of movies developed for the Marvel Cinematic Universe, and [Phase Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Phase_Two) refers to a second block of movies developed for the MCU. The MCU wiki also explains [Phase One](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_One) and [Phase Two](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_Two), plus it describes what will happen in [Phase Three](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_Three).